# How to use logic operators in jinja template on salt-stack (AND, OR)

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am using a jinja template to generate a state file for salt. I added some conditionals and would like to express:
`if A or B`. However, it seems I cannot get any logical operator working.

It doesn't like `||, |, &&`(which I understand doesn't apply here), but also not `and, or` and not even grouping with `()`, which should be working according to the [jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#logic). I couldn't find any information on this in the salt docs, but I feel I must be making some stupid mistake?

My code:

```
{% if grains['configvar'] == 'value' OR grains['configvar'] == 'some other value' %}
```

Error:

```
Data failed to compile:
Rendering SLS 'base:mystate' failed: Jinja syntax error: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'OR'; line 3
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are doing it right but the logic operators **need** to be **lower cased**.

Try switching all your operators to lower case.